# extract 7zip files in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, 7zip

I am trying to extract .7z files which is password protected.
In a particular folder path there are some .7z files format. First I have to extract all files in the same directory than I have to do another stuff with this files.

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

import { extractFull } from 'node-7z-forall';

const dirpath = path.join('C:/MyFolder/DATA')
   

fs.readdir(dirpath, function(err, files) {
  const txtFiles = files.filter(el => path.extname(el) === '.7z')
  console.log(txtFiles);
  

        extractFull(txtFiles, 'C:/MyFolder/DATA', { p: 'admin123' } /* 7z options/switches */)
       .progress(function (files) {
       console.log('Some files are extracted: %s', files);
});
})
```

I am using `node-7z-forall` module  but it is only working when I change the file format to `.js` to `.mjs`.  in .mjs file format file extract smoothly .but in .js format it is not working.

error:

```
import { extractFull } from 'node-7z-forall';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

How to handle this error. Is it possible to work with in .js format instead of .mjs format?
I am new in nodejs. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason it errors, it that ".js" indicates a commonjs file which uses require() but a ".mjs" file indicates a module which uses the import syntax.
This is also where the error comes from because you try to use import in a non module.
You can prevent the error by simply importing the package using require():

```
const { extractFull } = require('node-7z-forall');
```

Comment: Some files are extracted: []
Potentially unhandled rejection [2] Error:  The parameter is incorrect
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\WallE\Desktop\123\node_modules\node-7z-forall\util\run.js:100:15)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)

Comment: Now I am getting this error

Comment: This is an error with the library, you could submit an issue here: [issues](https://github.com/techno-express/node-7z-forall/issues)
Or look at the code [github](https://github.com/techno-express/node-7z-forall) to resolve the issue.